# Why won't my model unwrap?

Tags: mesh, uv

For some reason, my model won't unwrap.
I have uploaded the model here: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37735

One thing that surprises me is that if I try to select a ring, the ring stops at a certain vertex:

[image]

I have extended the ring manually, then clicked "Mark Seam", then I selected the upper lid and the lower lid of the barrel and also clicked "Mark Seam" for each of them.

When I now click 'u' and then 'Unwrap', nothing happens. I have been able to unwrap other models, but not this one.

Does anybody see where I might have missed something? Blender does not show any error message, it just doesn't unwrap.

Thank you for the help.

Edit: I have uploaded a new model here to reflect the suggested changes: I removed all doubles, I applied rotation & scale, and I put the same in a location where Blender could select a whole ring automatically.
But it still won't unwrap:

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37739

Edit 2: Now here is a simpler model without the handles. It is really absolutely simple geometry (I think), but it still won't unwrap:
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37741

Could anybody have a look again? Thank you!

Comment: Select the whole mesh (A) before pressing U-->Unwrap.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is impossible to select the whole edge using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+RMB. It is a matter of geometry you've got there.
 What you can do is select the upper edge/vertex and then (while holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button) the bottom one.
[image]

You may also select the upper vertex/edge, then (holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>) the bottom one and then go to *Select-->Shortest Path*.
[image]

QUICK TIP: I figured out that your origin point is located outside the mesh. It is a good habit to keep it inside. Being in *Edit Mode* select the whole mesh (<kbd>A</kbd>), press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>*-->Cursor to Selected* and then (being in *Object Mode*) <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>*-->Origin to 3D Cursor* to place an origin point inside a mesh.
[image]

Note: You'll probably have to delete the top and bottom ngons to make a proper unwrap. And make sure to remove the doubles (being in *Edit mode* select the whole mesh [<kbd>A</kbd>]), then press <kbd>W</kbd>*-->Remove Doubles*).

EDIT: I've unwrapped a mesh and the UV islands look like this:
[image]

Here's the .blend to download:
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37742

Comment: Also he need to add seams on the small parts on the top of the mesh to unwrap properly

Comment: Apply the rotation and scale in object mode (CTRL + A). and mark the seam in edit mode and then unwrap.

Comment: @Gonzou I think I did everything as you suggest, but it still wouldn't unwrap. Does it work for you?

Comment: @tmighty yeah, it works fine for me: http://www.gfycat.com/GiftedTintedIndochinesetiger
Please wait a minute and I'll post a .blend with an unwrapped mesh for you.

Comment: Thank you. I am excited to see where you have inserted additional seams. Before you did that, it wouldn't work for you, too, or would it? And did you stumble over all my mistake as well when you were a beginner?

Comment: @Gonzou And thanks for the file. I don't understand your seams logic on the handles yet. Can you explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I have found the cause. I should have posted the entire screen.

[image]

When I clicked the button left from the "View" button the left bottom and changed it to "UV/Image Editor", the UV unwrap became visible right away, so I would think that the model was indeed unwrapped but not shown.

If anybody can explain this, I would of course accept his solution.
Thank you!

Comment: Man, so that was your issue? I misunderstood your question a bit then :). Glad you've found a solution :). About the other question you have, please ask a separate one.

Comment: @Gonzou But I have learned a lot. Thank you. You have tweaked the UVs (http://i.stack.imgur.com/cOqbR.jpg) to be so "straight", right? There is no magic function that would do that automatically, right?

Comment: @Gonzou I don't understand your seams logic on the handles yet. Did you just insert enough seams to separate the handles from the barrel? If yes, then I don't understand why you have additional seams on the handle (and not just on its outer limits). Ahhh, I think I see now. The additional seems is make more guide lines. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: glad I helped :). Sorry but I can't answer all your questions here because the comments are not for extended discussion. We may chat about it. I placed the seams on the handles to separate them as the UV islands. I did it to avoid stretching (which may lead to texture deformations): http://www.pasteall.org/pic/92328 Remember, that  whenever you got a new question- just ask it as a separate one. Regards :).

Comment: @PaulGonet im having problem with my uv wrap i have posted the question but i did not get the answer. Can u plz make me clear. Mr Zak answer but it not clear me perfectly. The image having the edge and also look blur. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67249/how-to-remove-the-edge-partition

Comment: @atek Your answer is ready. Check it out here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67249/how-to-remove-the-edge-partition

Answer (score -1):

maybe you have accidentally PINNED your vertices in UV Editor... unpin those vertices (select vertices, then ALT+P)