# How to remove/blur the texture seam?

Tags: uv

I have unwrapped my mesh (using the seam placed in the center). I have scaled the object and applied transformations (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) . After applying the texture and unwrapping there is a partition edge between the texture. How to remove that edge partition or what wrong am I doing with the unwrap? The texture I've applied is *256x256*. Do I need a larger size image? It looks dull and not sharp like the original. [image][image]

Comment: That's just a seam in the texture.. which is visible exactly where seam on the mesh is placed. Make your texture [tiled](https://design.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-turn-a-texture-into-a-seamlessly-tiled-background--psd-1565) and apply it on the mesh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use a higher resolution texture (256X256 is really small) and hide the seams using texture paint brushes. Here's the result which uses the higher resolution texture and corrective brushes.
[image]

To get rid of the seam use a ***Clone*** brush in a *Texture Paint* mode. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> to place the cursor in the area you want to clone and then <kbd>LMB</kbd> to paint.
[image]

Use a ***Smear*** brush to blur the texture and hide the seams/imperfections.
[image]

***NOTE:*** *Don't forget to* ***save*** *your painted texture in the UV Editor!*

Here's the corrected .blend: [image]

---

Comment: wow amazing potato looks original. Thanks to give a brief explanation that i need. May i know u have use not looks mine. Have u done photoshop and increase the size or some other method

Comment: Glad to hear I helped :). I've downloaded the higher res texture from google graphics, used a clone tool and sharpened in photoshop to tweak it a bit.